# How to make the digital slot machine effect through CSS?

Tags: jquery, css

How to use CSS to achieve the rotating effect of the digital slot machine, I currently use javascript to achieve this effect (you can watch the example), but I want to know if I want to use CSS to achieve it but because my CSS is poor, someone can Provide a method? Thank you~

```js
//數字會慢慢跳動的動畫函式
 function countup() {
  var options = {
    useEasing: true,
    useGrouping: true,
    separator: '',
    decimal: ',',
    suffix: '',//單位
  };
  if(document.getElementById('workhour').textContent == '') { return }
// 6 是秒速
  var demo = new CountUp('workhour', 0, document.getElementById('workhour').textContent, 0, 6, options);
  if (!demo.error) {
  demo.start();
  } else {
    console.error(demo.error);
  }
}
countup();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/countup.js/1.8.2/countUp.min.js"></script>


 <div id="workhour" class="display-2 font-weight-bold  work_hour font-xl">999999</div>
```

Comment: Why do you want to do it in CSS if you can do it in Javascript?

Comment: You can't really do that in CSS, you have to use some JavaScript.

Comment: @AnyeHaha~Because I am simply curious about whether CSS can be completed, and I am also guessing whether using CSS is better for web pages.

Comment: @JeanWillOK~ It still seems to be done through javascript